# MySQL JOIN from three tables

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT title
     , event_date
     , event_end_date
     , individual_price
     , event_capacity
     , e.id
     , COUNT(r.event_id) registrants_count
     , COUNT(w.event_id) waiting_count 
  FROM ni803_eb_events e
  LEFT 
  JOIN ni803_eb_registrants r
    ON r.event_id = e.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN ni803_eb_waiting_lists w
    ON w.event_id = e.id
 WHERE event_capacity > 0 
 GROUP 
    BY event_date DESC;
```

I got three tables:

- ni803_eb_events - list of events with unique ID
- ni803_eb_registrants - list of people registered to events at every registrant there is event_id = ID from event list
- ni803_eb_waiting_lists - its just list of people who registered after event was full, same principal as registrants also there is event_id = ID of event which people registered to

I need to show ni803_eb_events where I COUNT rows from ni803_eb_registrants (id = event_id count number of same event_id) and also COUNT rows from ni803_eb_waiting_lists.

When I use just one of JOINs registrants or waiting_list it work just fine.... but not both of them :(

At screenshot below there is something wrong I marked it there are nowhere 69 registrants, there much more impossible numbers...

[image: Screenshot - result of my query]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry, actually is a simple query without any additional data or samples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you could get a Cartesian due to not always having records in either/or table.  I suggest doing the pre-aggregates grouped by ID within each sub-table.  Then those are left-joined to the original table of events.  So at MOST, there would be 1 record in the registrants or 1 record in the waiting, never more.  So your outermost query does not need a COUNT() or GROUP BY clause.  You get each event with the respective counts.

```
SELECT 
      title, 
      event_date, 
      event_end_date, 
      individual_price, 
      event_capacity, 
      e.id, 
      reg.regCnt as registrants_count, 
      wait.waitCnt as waiting_count 
   FROM 
      ni803_eb_events e
         LEFT JOIN 
         ( select r.event_id, COUNT(*) regCnt
              from ni803_eb_registrants r
              group by r.event_id ) reg
            ON e.id = reg.event_id
         LEFT JOIN 
         ( select w.event_id, COUNT(*) waitCnt
              from ni803_eb_waiting_lists w
              group by w.event_id ) wait
            ON e.id = wait.event_id
   WHERE 
      e.event_capacity > 0 
   order by
      event_date DESC;
```

Comment: Dont forget to upvote those answers that help you, and checkbox those that are the solution.  This way others know what has been solved and can help others too with similar issues.